# Find the order of factor group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The professor provided a simple example, such as the order of $\Bbb Z _6 / \langle 3 \rangle$: $|\Bbb Z _6| = 6$ and $| \langle 3 \rangle | = 2$, so $|
\Bbb Z _6 / \langle 3 \rangle | = 3$.

I thought "well, I got!" but I started practicing the topic "*factor group*" and I found something like this:

> find the order of factor group $(\Bbb Z _{12} \times \Bbb Z _4) / (\langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle)$.

I suppose that we multiply $12 \times 4$ because of $\Bbb Z _{12} \times \Bbb Z _4$ right? Do we do the same thing with the other side?

He provided this formula: $|\Bbb Z _n / \langle a \rangle| = n / |\langle a \rangle| = \dfrac n {\frac n {\gcd(n,a)}}$.

So, does $\Bbb Z _{12} \times \Bbb Z _4$ become $\Bbb Z _n$, and $\langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle$ become $\langle a \rangle$?

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for: do you want to find out the factor group, or just its order?

Comment: the questions "professor question" says `find the order of this factor group` so I guess I'm looking for the factor, but if you provide both to make me understand the topic better, I will be happy to see both =)

Comment: @AlexM.Thank you for your edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of $2$ in $\Bbb Z _{12}$ is $6$ (because $2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 0$), so $| \langle 2 \rangle | = 6$. Similarly, $| \langle 2 \rangle | = 2$ in $\Bbb Z _4$. Therefore, the order of $\langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle$ in $\Bbb Z _{12} \times \Bbb Z _4$ is $6 \cdot 2 = 12$.

The order of $\Bbb Z _{12} \times \Bbb Z _4$ is $12 \times 4$ (as you were suspecting), so by [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_%28group_theory%29) the order of the factor group $(\Bbb Z _{12} \times \Bbb Z _4) / \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle)$ is the quotient of the respective orders, that is $\dfrac {48} {12} = 4$.

In this extremely simple example the quotient group is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z _{12} / \langle 2 \rangle \times \Bbb Z _4 / \langle 2 \rangle = \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$, but keep in mind that in general it is **not** true that $(A \times B) / (I \times J) = A/I \times B/J$.

Comment: damn, now that you do that, it sounds very easy, so the hard part would be `find <a>` right?

Comment: @AMaduro: I cannot answer this question, since difficulty is subjective. I would say that a much harder problem is to find factor groups which, fortunately, was really easy in your problem.

Comment: Oooo! I'm not a math major lol so, I THINK (don't believe me) but I think I shouldn't worry about that, for now. I'm looking some pass exams, and I don't see anything saying "find the factor group" and this is abstract algebra so, not sure he will talk about `find a factor group`, tankkk youuu very much for your answer! really help me

Comment: 1 last question, so should I worry about the formula that he provided or not?

Comment: @AMaduro: No, his formula is correct, you could use it like this: first, note that $( \Bbb Z _{12} \times \Bbb Z _4 ) / ( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle ) \simeq ( \Bbb Z _{12} / \langle 2 \rangle ) \times ( \Bbb Z _4 / \langle 2 \rangle )$, so $ | ( \Bbb Z _{12} \times \Bbb Z _4 ) / ( \langle 2 \rangle \times \langle 2 \rangle ) | = | \Bbb Z _{12} / \langle 2 \rangle | \cdot | \Bbb Z _4 / \langle 2 \rangle |$ and now apply the said formula for each of the two factors.

Comment: Ooo got it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$(\mathbf Z_{12}\times\mathbf Z_4)/(2\mathbf Z_{12}\times2\mathbf Z_4)\simeq\mathbf Z_{12}/2\mathbf Z_{12}\times\mathbf Z_4/2\mathbf Z_4\simeq\mathbf Z_2\times\mathbf Z_2,$$
by the *third isomorphism theorem*, hence the order of the quotient is $4$.

Comment: I don't follow, I think that some lower indices are mistaken (typos, I mean), which leads to a mistaken final result. Your starting point is not the one in the question.

Comment: Better, but still not good: $2 \Bbb Z _{12} \simeq \Bbb Z _6$, so the first factor of the result is $\Bbb Z _2$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the typos, I've corrected. But it is not clear to me what   you mean with ‘[my] starting point is not the one in the question’?

Comment: ah! =) I think I also deserve +1, because you also learn something from my question =) @Bernard

Comment: The l.h.s. of your line of equalities was not the one in the OP; now it is, but there is a mistake in the result.

Comment: Oops!  I messed up  applying the third isomorphism theorem! Thank you, I'll corect that.